# Headings when using autodoc in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, autodoc

I have a documentation file that looks like this:

```
##
H1
##

Blah Blah

**
H2
**
Blah Blah

H3
==

Blah Blah

H4
--

Blah Blah

.. automodule:: lib.X
   :members:
```

The Python file `X.py` looks like this:

```
"""
Another H3
==========

Blah Blah
"""

Lots of stuff
```

My problem is that the first heading from the module docstring in `X.py` is rendered in HTML in the same way as the last heading in the original document `H4`, instead of being rendered as a third level heading. Am I doing something wrong or have I found a problem in Sphinx?

Comment: @bad-coder, replace "Lots of stuff" with  "    pass" in my supplied code and you have a minimal example. The only relevant thing is that the doctree contains a Sphinx header The rest of the Python file is totally irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: I agree with this but it leaves Python module docstrings and @include files as second-class citizens. One potential solution which requires Docutils and Sphinx support is to be able to state that whatever hearing hierarchy that has been discovered, still governs. This does nothing about the problems in using subordinate documents within a master. Another solution is to add a DocUtils directive that states that headings within a subordinate document are relative to the hierarchy already discovered. Thus the subordinate documents could always start at level 1 and would still fit.

Comment: Your suggestion works in the current Sphinx environment and if you turn it into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a misconception to include [*reST* structural elements](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#document-structure) in a docstring, namely [Sections](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) (headings) and [Transitions](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#transitions) (Sphinx should issue a warning if you try). Don't confuse the former with [Docstring sections](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#383-functions-and-methods). **Both are called sections**, but that is where the similarities end.

Because, if you want to include a given module or class in two different `.rst` files, using `autodoc` directives, the fixed headings (structural element) inside the docstring may not align with the different hierarchy of headings in the `.rst` files.

This would create a structural constraint, the `.rst` file heading hierarchy would depend on the placing of your `autodoc` directives in it. Conceptually, I think control of structure should depend only on the `.rst` file.

Plus, the [section adornments style](https://docutils.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#id1) once encountered defines a heading level, so different placings of your `autodoc` directives would end up taking control of the `.rst` structure. (And lets not forget, if your output is HTML you'll be limited to 6 levels of headings, so using them in docstrings would further limit your structural options in the `.rst`...)

**How does docutils factor into this equation? (mentioned by OP in the comments.)**

Don't worry about docutils!! A regular Python developer only needs Sphinx (which entails **reST**) to write nice documentation. The use of docutils would be to write costum Sphinx extensions, but for the majority of uses stable extensions/directives are already provided.

Comment: It is not correct that the heading hierarchy must be the same in all documents that are included in a `toctree`. The sequence of heading adornments can be different in each document. There is no real collision and there are no warnings.

Comment: This could be an interesting discussion, but does it really belong here? `toctree` is not even mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pages get parsed independently, without knowledge of the adornment symbols/hierarchy you adopt in other pages.  The H1/H2/H3 sequence is [simply the order as encountered](https://docutils.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections).

For example, try moving your `.. automodule::` chunk from bottom of the documentation file (i.e. 5th heading encountered) to the top (i.e. 1st heading) and it's styling will update.

So the section heading in your Python file gets styled H1 viewed in there... or H5 when embedded into the documentation file.

Comment: @bad_coder, I removed the last `H4` so that the last level became an `H3` and the first heading in my Python module got rendered as an `H4`. I am used to using the Python documentation conventions for marking headings, but it seems that something funny happens to the heading hierarchy when you cross an `automodule` boundary. This is nested within a subsidiary `toctree` but I do not seem to have any problems at that level. The problem with CSS is that it relies on the HTML being marked up correctly.

Comment: @bad-coder, to me, documentation fits into a wider environment so I am both attracted to, and affected by the synthesis of different systems. Right now I want to use Sphinx headers in the modules that are accessed through automodule so I am trying to figure out the rules so that for example, the documentation within a module can be used within different high-level documents with different heading hierarchies. I feel that this may be a missing part of Sphinx.

Comment: I routinely use reST section headings in Python module-level docstrings; no warnings or 'collisions' occur; Sphinx calmly rolls up content from multiple sources by nesting their hierarchies. The `.. contents::`, `.. toctree::`, `.. include::` directives and HTML sidebars all "just work" logically and as you'd expect. The original question was clear but conversation seems to have moved to a philosophical debate on documentation style.